# mongo query that has regex returns null for string that contains special character as ^

Tags: java, mongodb

My mongoDb Json structure is

```
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "name" : "john",
    "description" : "sales^category",
    "source" : "employed"

},
```

In the above description attribute has some special characters. Like (*, !) etc

I want to fetch the records where description contains sales^category.

From the above mongo query has to return id 1234.

I tried to do escape with \ and also tried as  [^] but this is not matching the record. Please advice.

Comment: You "escape" special characters with ``\``

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. PLease advice on below item.   I have a string as String str = M^*%$!@**>>>%% . Now how to deal with special character ^ , Because of this substring query is not found. I tried with escape with [^] and \\^ but this didn't worked for me. Please advice.

Comment: If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)